# Replace values of duplicate rows based on the same datetime in another column but keep the last row unchanged

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace, duplicates

Hi I have a data frame that looks like this. Based on the same datetime, I need to keep the last row as 1 and replace the remaining ones as 0. Is there anyway for me to do this?

```
DateTimeStarted          Value
0   2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
1   2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
2   2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
3   2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
4   2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
5   2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
6   2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
7   2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
8   2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
9   2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
10  2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
11  2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
12  2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
13  2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
14  2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
15  2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
16  2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
17  2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
18  2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
19  2020-12-26 18:00:00  1
20  2020-12-26 18:00:00  1
21  2020-12-27 13:00:00  0
22  2020-12-27 14:00:00  0
23  2020-12-27 15:00:00  0
24  2020-12-27 15:00:00  0
25  2020-12-27 17:00:00  0
```

The solution should look like this. The values 0 should also remained unchanged.

```
DateTimeStarted          Value
0   2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
1   2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
2   2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
3   2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
4   2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
5   2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
6   2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
7   2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
8   2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
9   2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
10  2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
11  2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
12  2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
13  2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
14  2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
15  2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
16  2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
17  2020-12-19 16:00:00  0
18  2020-12-19 16:00:00  1
19  2020-12-26 18:00:00  0
20  2020-12-26 18:00:00  1
21  2020-12-27 13:00:00  0
22  2020-12-27 14:00:00  0
23  2020-12-27 15:00:00  0
24  2020-12-27 15:00:00  0
25  2020-12-27 17:00:00  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
((~df.DateTimeStarted.duplicated(keep='last')) & (df.Value.ne(0))).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    1
19    0
20    1
21    0
22    0
23    0
24    0
25    0
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Hi is there any advantage over apply method if we use the factorize method?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using`apply` method, but `apply` is almost like using `for` loop in dataframes which is slow and not efficient. But by using numpy and pandas methods and function, you are enjoying vectorizing calculations. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) for more info.

Comment: are you sure that your `factorize()` method is faster than `apply()` method?

Comment: Sorry, I understood your expected output wrong. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Anurag Dabas , for big datasets I believe it is!

Comment: Apologies I didnt make myself clear enough. my dataset also have values that are zero so that has to be remained unchanged. The above code will change all the last row of the unique datetime to be 1.

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) method and stored unique value in a variable:

```
uniquedf=df[~df.duplicated(subset=['DateTimeStarted'],keep='last')]
```

Now set 'Value' column of you `df` equal to `0`:

```
df['Value']=0
```

Then make use of [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method and [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method:

```
result=uniquedf.reindex(df.index).fillna(df)
```

Finally change the dtype of 'Value' column by [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) method:

```
result['Value']=result['Value'].astype(int)
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output

Comment: Hi sorry the apply method is not working out well. What happens is that I have other rows with other datetime in the dataframe and each of the last unique datetime row has been replaced with 1. Is there a workaround for this method?